# Hiding an equation tag but still using it for referencing

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing

I use the `semantic` package for displaying natural deduction-style inference rules in equations. The `\inference` command has an optional argument which can be used to tag rules:

```
\inference[Rule1]{A}{B}
```

When I use the inference rule in an equation of `amsmath` environment, I would like to be able to label the inference rule and use 'Rule1' as the reference name in the rest of the document. However, if I use `\tag{Rule1}`/`\tag*{Rule1}` the equation tag is (of course) displayed too. I've tried various ways of making the tag invisible, but since the `\tag` command does not itself render anything, nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to hide the equation tag but still tell LaTeX to use a custom tag name whenever the label is referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{semantic}

\makeatletter
\def\@inferenceFrontName[#1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
  \ltx@label{semantic\detokenize{#1}}%
  \setbox3=\hbox{\footnotesize #1}%
  \ifdim \wd3 > \z@
    \unhbox3%
    \hskip\@@nSpace
  \fi
  \@inferenceMiddle
}
\newcommand{\ruleref}[1]{\ref{semantic\detokenize{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\inference[Rule1]{A}{B}
\end{equation*}

\ruleref{Rule1}

\end{document}
```

[image]